# How to append a pickled data to a file in python?

Tags: python, pickle

```
import pickle

def user():
    name_input = raw_input("Name: ")
    age_input = raw_input("Age: ")
    email_input = raw_input("E-Mail: ")
    ph_input = raw_input("Phone Number: ")
    user_input = {'Name': name_input, 'Age': age_input, 'E-Mail': email_input, 'Phone number': ph_input}
    return user_input

a = user()
with open("picke.txt", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(a,f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

b = "abc"
with open("picke.txt", "wb") as fi:
    pickle.dump(b,fi, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

When a file is opened, pickle dumped and closed.Again I open the same file to pickle.dump in it. It does not append to the file but overwrites it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new "picke.txt" with the lines:

```
with open("picke.txt", "wb") as fi:
    pickle.dump(a, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

You need to open in `ab` mode to append, not `wb` mode to write a new file as follows:

```
with open("picke.txt", "ab") as fi:
    pickle.dump(a, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same problem, and the answer provided before did not work for me, using Python3.7

My solution is opening the file in 'ab' mode, use pickle to convert your object to binary ([pickle.dumps()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) not pickle.dump()) and write this to the file in a second step.

```
with open('picke.txt', 'ab') as fi:
    bin_obj = pickle.dumps(obj)
    fi.write(bin_obj)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The likely reason why it didn't work is that the `dump` method dumps to a file-like object by convention (compare `json.dump` and `json.dumps` :))

Comment: Yes, I was just hoping that opening the file in append mode would prevent pickle from overwriting data already saved in the file.